# Flutter showModalBottomSheet where the sheet is not dismissible?

Tags: material-design, flutter

I want to utilize a modal bottom sheet for data entry.  I don't want the user to be able to dismiss it by just touching outside the sheet.  This article describes how to do it in Android native.

https://medium.com/@betakuang/make-your-bottomsheetdialog-noncancelable-e50a070cdf07

How can I do this with the flutter widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **alternative** to a *modal* [`BottomSheet`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) is a [*persistent* `BottomSheet`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html).

The only change you need to make is changing `showModalBottomSheet` to `showBottomSheet`.

The *persistent* `BottomSheet` can still be dismissed by e.g. pressing the back button *on Android*. This is *nice* behavior, as in it is *Material* behavior.

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider that the "persistent" one was dismissible.  I will look at that.  Thanks.

Comment: @dakamojo If it was helpful, you can upvote the answer or accept it, so your question is considered "answered".

Answer (score 11):

Here

- setting **enableDrag** **false** disables dragging of bottom sheet
- setting **isDismissable** **false** disables on cancel on outside touch
- returning empty on **onWillPop** overrides back button so user can't go back using back button

  ```
   showModalBottomSheet(
     enableDrag: false,
     isDismissible: false,
     context: context,
     builder: (context) {
       return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {},
        child: Container());
     });
  ```

Comment: You need to return false inside onWillPop scope to disable back button.     onWillPop: () async {
                return false;
              },

Answer (score 3):

this practice worked for me!!

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    isDismissible: false, // <--- this line
    clipBehavior: ,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0), topRight: Radius.circular(25.0)),
    ),
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
         SizedBox(height: 250,)
        ]),
      );

   });
```